# Popping a non-root view controller on app launch (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a working application with a `UITableViewController` as a root view controller.

I need to pop a simple log-in screen on app launch,

and i can't set it as root view controller because it's against the project properties.

also, im using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, in root view controller (UITableViewController in your case) viewDidAppear's method, present log-in screen as modalViewController. You need to set the Identifier for your ViewController first.

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"
                                                 bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *lgn = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
[self presentViewController:lgn animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Use your own storyboard and viewController names.

Comment: i need to initialize with a nib for this method to work and i am working with storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In App Delegate

```
loginViewController = [[BANLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BANLoginViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

[window addSubView:[navController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And in the `BANLoginViewController` you could check if the user is logged in or not and then initialise the main storyboard.